# Expected expression before 'struct' asd

Tags: c, struct

So I have this piece of code but I keep getting the error I've put in title.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum discout
{
    nou = 5,
    medium = 10,
    avansat = 15,
    expert = 20,
};
typedef struct memberName
{

    char fname[20];
    char lname[20];
} mName[100];

struct memberInfo
{
    int age;
    char CNP[20];
    char country;
    char city;
} mInfo[100];

void addMember()
{
    int i=0;
    while(mName[i].fname!='\0')
        i++;
    scanf("%18s",mName[i].fname);
    scanf("%18s",mName[i].lname);
    i++';
}

void addInfo()
{

}

void addStatut()
{

}

void addDiscout()
{

}

void modifyMember()
{

}

void addHairstylist()
{

}
int main()
{
    int alegere;
    printf("\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\tBun venit!\n\n\n");
    printf("\tCe ati dori sa faceti?\n\n");
    printf("\t1. Adauga un membru;\n\t2. Adauga informatii despre membru;\n\t3. Adauga suma cheltuita de membru;\n\t4. Modifica numele unui client\n\t5. Ofera statut unui membru;\n\t6.Afiseaza informatiile despre un membru;\n\t7.Afiseaza toti membti;");
    scanf("%d",&alegere);
    switch (alegere)
    {
    case 1:
        addMember();
        break;
    case 2:
        addInfo();
        break;
    case 3:
        addDiscout();
        break;
    case 4:
        modifyMember();
        break;
    case 5:
        addHairstylist();
        break;
    default:
        printf("Ati introdus o valoare necunoscuta!\n");
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Do you have any idea why is that? Thanks in advance.
I have changed the code. Now I displayed the full code as it is. Any ideas?

Comment: `while(struct mName[i].fname!=0)` --> `while(mName[i].fname!=0)` and rest of the cases.

Comment: You should initialize i.

Comment: BTW that code does not make much sense, anyway.

Comment: Why not just `scanf("℅s",mName.fname[i]);` ? And why does the while loop say `!= 0` ? I think you ment `\0` ?

Comment: `scanf("%18c",struct mName.fname[i]);` ==> `scanf("%18s", mName[i].fname);` and others similar. But the intent of the code seems flaky anyway, earlier you test `mName[i].fname!=0` what is that supposed to do?

Comment: @WeatherVane i put struct there because I didn;'t used typedef struct memberName;

Comment: @maheshRao thanks for observation, I changed that, but still the same error

Comment: Did you remove the "struct" in the while loop ?

Comment: @EduardLatcan remove `struct` when referencing it. That was not the only change, look carefully and you will see I changed `%c` to `%s` and moved the array indexing `[i]` to index the array of structs, not the string member.

Comment: @SouravGhosh the void function I'm using is for adding ellements in the mName[100] array from the struct, but get that error

Comment: Also, it would be better, if you could check the line of the code, that is specified in the error

Comment: @WeatherVane I did changed as you said but still getting the same error. That while is for verifiying where the last name was added into the array

Comment: I suggest you try printing (or tracing) the value of `i` before using it, because a) `i` is not initialised (as already mentioned) and b) `while(mName[i].fname!=0)` does not do what you imagine.

Comment: @WeatherVane I have initialised "i". What you mean by "b)" be more concise please..

Comment: @WeatherVane i also changed !=0 with !='\0' as mahesh pointed

Comment: In my test (`i` uninitialised) I get `i=-17940` and again, when I have initialised `int i=0;` I get `i=429062636`. So a) initialise `i` and b) think hard exactly what that loop is supposed to do, and c) make sure you limit `i` or you will break the struct array. (Note: comparing a string with `'\0'` is nonsense. You cannot compare a string with an equality test in C).

Comment: @EduardLatcan Try `while(mName[i].fname[0]!='\0')`

Comment: it does not work....

Comment: Could you add the exact error as it is given, in the question ? if it's possible ?

Comment: expected expression before 'mName' ..

Comment: And the line of code which the error specifies?

Comment: the error is at the void function. everywhere i use the "mName[i].asd"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following changes:

```
int i=0;
while(mName[i].fname[0]!='\0')
    i++;
scanf("%s",mName[i].fname);
scanf("%s",mName[i].lname);
```

Also remove the typedef for the structure. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Remove typedef given to struct